# How to calculate this limit, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\alpha_k\beta_{n,k}$?

Tags: limits

I would like to calculate the following limit:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\alpha_k\beta_{n,k}.
$$

I know that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\beta_{n,k}=1$ and the series $\sum_{k\geqslant0}\alpha_k$ converges to $\ell$.

If I think about it I found the limit is $\ell$. I mean if I do something which is not math like:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\alpha_k\beta_{n,k}=
\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\alpha_k\right)\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\beta_{n,k}\right)=\ell\cdot1=\ell.\blacksquare
$$

I am sure this is wrong. Can you please help me.

P.S. As an example, one can take the following sequences:

$$
\alpha_k=\dfrac{1}{k!}.
$$

and

$$
\beta_{n,k}=\dfrac{\prod\limits_{p=0}^{k-1}(n-p)}{n^k}.
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need here is uniform convergence on the $\beta_{n,k}$'s as well as absolute convergence of the sum $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \alpha_k$. That is for each $\epsilon > 0$ there is an $N$ for which $|\beta_{n,k} - 1| < \epsilon$ for all $n > N$ and all $k$.

With this we have $$ (1-\epsilon)\sum_{k=0}^\infty |\alpha_k| \le \sum_{k=0}^\infty |\alpha_k| |\beta_{n,k}| \le (1+\epsilon)\sum_{k=0}^\infty |\alpha_k|$$

Hence $\sum_{k=0}^\infty |\alpha_k| |\beta_{n,k}|$ converges to $\sum_{k=0}^\infty |\alpha_k|$ which means $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \alpha_k \beta_{n,k}$ converges.

For your example all the terms are positive for $\alpha_k$, so the sum converges absolutely. And you should check if $\beta_{n,k}$ is converging uniformly to 1.

Comment: But $\beta_{n,k}$ must depends on $n$ so that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\beta_{n,k}=1$.

Comment: Very true. I will fix this.

Comment: Oh wait I see the problem... hmm.. I will have to give it more thought.

Comment: There, I hope this helps.